# Running ser cable from 200amp main to 100 amp sub panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, service

I'm running ser wire from my 200 amp main box in my garage to a 100amp service box for tankless water heater. I'm running the cable along the top edge of my garage around a corner about 30ft run total. I was wondering how I need to secure this 2-2-2-4 cable along the top of my garage ceiling? I know I ser does not require conduit so can I just wire clamps or what? I was going to secure with wire clamps every 3 ft of run and then cover with some angled crown molding?? Just trying to make sure I won't have to tear down if I ever sell my house. Thanks!

Comment: How much power does your tankless water heater pull?

Comment: It pulls about 42amps on each side of 200 main panel only when demanded.

Answer (score 5):

### Your support plans are fine; just make sure your feeder breaker is 90A or less

SER cable used for feeder or branch-circuit duty is treated exactly the same as a (rather fat) NM cable for support and installation-technique purposes, albeit without the 60°C working temperature limit on ampacity calculations:

> **(4) Installation Methods for Branch Circuits and Feeders.**
>
> (a) Interior Installations. In addition to the provisions of
> this article, Type SE service-entrance cable used for interior
> wiring shall comply with the installation requirements of Part II
> of Article 334, excluding 334.80.

As a result, since the NEC only requires NM cables to be supported at a 4½' interval:

> **334.30 Securing and Supporting.** Nonmetallic-sheathed cable
> shall be supported and secured by staples; cable ties listed and
> identified for securement and support; or straps, hangers, or
> similar fittings designed and installed so as not to damage the
> cable, at intervals not exceeding 1.4 m (4½ ft) and within
> 300 mm (12 in.) of every cable entry into enclosures such as
> outlet boxes, junction boxes, cabinets, or fittings. Flat cables
> shall not be stapled on edge.
>
> Sections of cable protected from physical damage by raceway
> shall not be required to be secured within the raceway.

Note, though, that while people may say that your 2-2-2-4 SER cable is good for 100A, that's only true when it's feeding an *entire dwelling unit* (house or aparment); for other applications, like yours, you're limited to the 90A ampacity of a 2AWG Al wire at 75°C by the NEC 110.14(C) termination temperature limits, unless you have an old main panel that isn't marked for 75°C usage, which then limits you to 80A instead.

### GO BIG OR GO HOME

Assuming you haven't already acquired the subpanel, there's no reason to skimp on subpanel spaces.  While the heater may only require 4 or 6 slots for its own use, a 24-space or 30-space, 100A or 125A, main lug subpanel isn't that much more expensive than a mini-panel, and will provide valuable expansion room in the future.  This is especially true since the home of the new panel needs to provide a fridge-sized clearspace in front of it as per NEC 110.26(A) so that someone who has to work on the thing while "live" doesn't have to do a contortionist act to get to it.

Note that when you're hooking this panel up, since it's a *subpanel* (i.e. doesn't have a *service disconnect* inside it) powered by a *feeder*, you'll need to pull the green bonding screw *out* of its home in the panel, or simply not install it to begin with, and make sure that you install and use separate *grounding bars* to land your grounding wires in the panel if the panel doesn't come with them already fitted.

### TORQUE ALL LUGS TO SPEC

Last but not least, you'll want to use an inch-pound torque wrench and/or torque screwdriver when tightening breaker and lug connections.  This is required by 110.14(D) in 2017 and newer editions of the NEC, and is a good idea *anyway*, lest your electrical system [lose you the race](https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/2010/07/16/the-difference-between-success-and-failure-how-a-torque-wrench-improves-system-reliability/)!

Comment: Wow!!!  you're full of code this morning.  :-)